# append data into QByteArray

Tags: qt, qstring, qbytearray

I want to write a QString '***str***' into QByteArray '***baData***'.

The 'baData' is having **fixed size 80 Bytes** (it's requirment).

If the '***str***' size is **less than 80**, append the remaining data of '***baData***' with **0 (zero)** value.

I wrote following code, but not working porperly.

```
void MyClass::CopyData(QByteArray &packet)

{

         packet.truncate(0);
         packet[0] = 0x12;
         packet[1] = 0x34;
         ....

         QByteArray baData;
         baData.resize(80);
         baData = 0;

        QString str = "Hello Wrold";

        baData = str.toLocal8Bit();

        packet.append(baData, 80);

}
```

packet size is not fixed, but baData size if fixed i.e. 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
QByteArray baData;
baData.fill(0, 80);

QString str = "Hello World";
baData.insert(0, str.toLocal8Bit());
baData.resize(80);
```

Basically how it works is, you fill the `QByteArray` with 80 bytes of 0s, insert your data in the beginning and then resize it back to 80 bytes.

Comment: is there need for resize(), because it works without resize(),
If my 'str' is more than 80 bytes, I want to write only first 80 byte, how do I handle this.

Comment: @beparas If you want it to be 80 bytes long, then you need to resize it. If your `str` is longer than 80 bytes, `baData` will contain only the first 80 bytes in the example above.

Comment: Careful. QByteArray::resize() will not result in a null terminated string. If you need a null terminated QByteArray of 80-cahracters, then resize to one less - 79. QByteArray::data() is always null terminated with at least size()+1 accessible chars.